# PHP FPDF output with F option

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am using the FPDF and FPDM classes. I have built a pretty large application form which when submitted the data is taken and pushed to a PDF.

```
$fields = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $key => $val){
    $fields[$key] = $val;
}
$pdf = new FPDM('../pdfs/limited1.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false);
$pdf->Merge();
$filename="/srv/http/csignup/pdfs/abc.pdf";
$pdf->Output('F', $filename);
```

With the code above a pdf will be saved but all of the fields are blank, if I change the output function to:

```
$pdf->Output('I'); //open in browser
```

or

```
$pdf->Output('D'); //download
```

I get the pdf with all the fields filled in. Am I missing something blatantly obvious or is this expected behaviour?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference if you look at the [source](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF/blob/master/fpdf.php#L980). Maybe it's your PDF viewer that thinks your PDF is untrusted or something? Interesting question.

Comment: Not all pdf readers support dynamic fields. Try to open the saved pdf inside your browser

Comment: oh jeez now I do feel stupid haha. @LucaRainone thank you I would have been there all day!